# Hibernate - stores items on the same place in memory?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

let me show you a little code:

```
public Book getBookById(Long id) {
   Book book= bookRepository.findBookById(id);

   if (book.getAccount() != accountService.getLoggedAccount()) {
      return null;
   }

   return book;
}
```

And getLoggedAccount method:

```
public Account getLoggedAccount() {
    Account account = accountRepository.findAccountByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    if(account == null){
        return null;
    }

    account.getBooks().forEach(l -> l.setAuthors(null));
    return account;

}
```

What is the problem? The line:

```
account.getBooks().forEach(l -> l.setAuthors(null));
```

set authors to "null" in book got in **getBookById**.
So the result of method getBookById is book but with authors set to null. Why is that and how to change it?

Comment: Delete that line?

Comment: Is it possible to separate this object? I got "book" earlier, then I used getLoggedAccount and because of this book exists in account's book list, the earlier got "book" authors was set to null. I don't understand this.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/